# Running as a Web Server

Tags: web-server, gsm

I have a RPI 4.

I am running buster os

I have created a web serer.

I use nginx to handle connections

If I access it via my private network it works well.

If I now use a GSM modem on-board my rpi) and try to access my web site via the IP address assigned to that modem it does not work at all.

I can see the as soon as I request a web page the ip address assigned is changed making the call 403.

Upon Googling I found this is something that the telecoms do to stop people doing what I am trying to do.

Are there ways around this?

Comment: Try a different port on nginx. Something like 8080 which is the alternative HTTP port. They can't block everything. You should than be able to access it via http(s)://[hostname|ip]:8080/

Comment: Most GSM service providers block in-bound connections. You're not allowed to run servers over their networks.

Comment: @kwasmich thanks I shall test when home :)

Comment: @Dougie ... but I am suspect your are correct and looking at ur profile I guess you have the authority in this - thanks

Comment: @Andrew Simpson, One solution is ask your service provider to give you a static IP address, but they would charge you much extra fees, and might still limit your traffic because your web server is too popular and the whole world likes it.

Comment: It's also highly likely that for IPv4 out-bound traffic that an service provider is using CG-NAT (carrier grade - network address translation) which means up to 64K users get to share a single public IPv4 address. Having a NAT between you and the public internet makes it impossible to run a server. My public internet facing Raspberry is sitting on a broadband line with a dynamic IPv4 address. I use No-IP to give that a domain name.

Comment: @dougie thanks. Very informative. I was looking up the disadvantages of this setup. If I am pinging my server say 6 times a second (hosted with fasthosts etc will that pose an issue do you think?

Comment: I think the key point here, as identified correctly by @Dougie, is that you're trying to do this over GSM. Providers can - to some extent - filter traffic differently from each other, but I think few will let you do the inbound connection over GSM.

Comment: @Brick thanks. From all these answers from everyone I am understanding the situation.  Not sure about using vpns as this is an extra cost and something a 3rd party woud need to supply me. I am now focusing on uploading my sensor data from RPI via GSM to my hosted server and serving my web pages from that hosted service,  I am now focusing on whether there will be any restriction/throttling from RPI to my web server (output) via GSM by the provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are answers and comments addressing the question of why this probably isn't working and why it may not be workable as you're doing it now. Regarding the part of your question about how to work around it, I think the most straightforward ways would be either:

1. Use a proxy with a VPN connection in between
2. Send your data from the device connected via GSM to another machine that's got a more conventional connection to the internet.

Either of these require a different computer that's connected to the internet, and you'd give out the IP address of that second computer to anyone (including yourself) trying to access your server.

In the first case, it has to run a VPN service that your GSM-connected phone can access and then forward the http(s) requests via VPN to the computer on the GSM side.

In the second case, you'd have your GSM connected phone send updates to the webserver periodically, but the webserver would directly respond to any incoming http(s) requests.

It is *not* generally true that you need a static IP address for the webserver, but if you don't have one then you need to update any clients (include public DNS if you have a domain name for it) wanting to access it each time its public IP changes.  If you are the only user and your provider does not, in practice, change your IP address often, this may be no problem.  No-IP, mentioned in a comment, is one of several services that will manage this for you if you don't have a static address.

This is an issue distinct from whether they are blocking certain types of traffic or certain ports, which they may or may not do regardless of whether your IP address is dynamic or static.  You'll have to figure out what your provider is doing because we don't have enough specific information about your case to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks.  using vpns as this is an extra cost and something a 3rd party would need to supply me. focusing option 2.

Comment: You can run your own VPN. It never occurred to me that you'd use a third-party for that, although that is possible.

Comment: More specifically, you can run the VPN software just on these two machines so that they are the only machines on it and there is no additional hardware. Multiple options for this, but I think `strongswan` is the most conventional choice.

Comment: Sorry for these additional questions. I have my RPI and I have many various clients trying to access my RPI server, Where would I put the VPN?

Comment: Ah OK. So I would need VPN setup on the clients so for my purposes cannot do. Thanks for all the info.

Comment: Put strongswan on the Pi that's connected via GSM and on whatever other machine that you have with a "conventional" internet connection. Have them establish a VPN between them. Give the public IP of the machine on the conventional end to clients.  Have the webserver on the conventional end forward the http request to the GSM-machine through the VPN tunnel. Clients never know that it went to the GSM machine.

Comment: Just to make sure this right.I have strongswan on the RPI. Then also on my web server. Client connects initially to my VPN on my hosted server. I link up the tunnel. Afterwards wil any data pass from RPI to my Hosted Server to my clients. What I am trying to avoid here is any data going to my hosted server but directly t from RPI to my clients. Never worked with vpns you see :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99145/discussion-between-brick-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Brick Sorry, it was my fault. I have overseen the GSM modem as part of the RasPi. It's a right question and of course answer here. I have deleted my other comments about this.

Comment: @Brick Hi, if I have strongswan installed on Rpi I assume that  I would need strongswan installed on client pc as well to create the tunnel?

Comment: You need something on both ends, but not necessarily strongswan. The ends communicate via a protocol. Similar to how an http request (e.g. a web page) can be transmitted between your computer and the server without knowing which server is running on the other end and what hardware they have, the VPN could be established between dis-similar hardware and with different software on each end. Probably if you're at that point, you need a new question, maybe on https://superuser.com/help/on-topic instead of here.

Answer (score 2):

With most providers you will get a private IP address, usually one like 10.x.y.z. This is not reachable from the internet. That is not necessarily to stop people from doing what you want to do, but to conserve public IP addresses.

If your providers assigns IPv6 addresses, you may be able to use them.

Otherwise, you can use a VPN connection to some VPN provider. These are usually not free, they want wither your money or information about you.

Comment: I don't know about "most" providers, but I get a public IP address home and using my phone as a hotspot. (Also at work, but that is, as you noted, a static IP.)  At home, I can run a server if I port forward and keep track of which IP they give me. (My home is not static, and so the IP can and sometimes does change, but it's always a public IP.)  Over phone, I believe the traffic is just blocked even though I get a public IP assigned.  I think this answer is wrong at least so far as it is stated as a general conclusion rather than the practice of some specific provider.

Comment: The more I read the comments in this question and answers, the more discouraged me, a newbie in this area, became, because there are too many tedious prerequisite stuff I need to build up. I am hoping IPv6 and 5G would come in a year or two, and I would start learning.